# Rails extended "show" function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I'm beginner and can't figure out where to start with this problem.

I have fully functional `Entities Controller` where I can make new Entity and add all info I need.

Now I would like to have simple button on `Show` page that will direct me from `Example/entities/12` to `Example.com/entities/12/custom_view` page and render `entities` view called `custom_view` plus passing info of Entity with id =12. So I can display all info of particular entity.

I hope it is not very confusing, but I really don't know where to begin. I made my `entity controller` through `rails generate scaffold` command.

Hope you can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much things to do to achieve that. It's pretty easy. From what I understand you need url like "/entities/12/custom_view" and you want to find entity with id 12 and render the that entity info in custom_view template. Her's how to achieve that:

1. Add a route for new action

   ```
   # routes.rb
   resources :entities do
    member do
      get 'custom_view'
    end
   end
   ```
2. Add an action in controller, find entity

   ```
   # entities_controller
   def custom_view
    @entity = Entity.find(params[:id])
   end
   ```
3. Create a view template

   ```
   # views/entities/custom_view.html.erb
   # you can use @entity object to show your entity attributes
   <p>@entity.inspect</p>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed :D Where do you learn all this? in rails guides?

Comment: It is the basic flow from route to view in rails. What you are trying to achieve is an additional restful action besides the standard rails controller actions. Learn more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions